# JavaScript WebSQL databases

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm having a problem with my code below.

```js
db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);

if(!db) {   alert("Failed to connect to database.");    }

else {

function doQuery(queryType,query) {

function errorHandler(tr, error) {
alert('Oops.  Error was: '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
var we_think_this_error_is_fatal = true;
if (we_think_this_error_is_fatal) return true;
return false;
}

if(queryType == "SELECT") {
function dataHandler(tr, rs) {alert("1")}
db.transaction(function (tr) {  tr.executeSql(query,[],dataHandler,errorHandler)})
}

else { 
function dataHandler(tr, rs) { alert("2")}
db.transaction(function (tr) {  tr.executeSql(query,[],dataHandler,errorHandler)})
}

} // doquery
} // else
```

db, tables, and records already was inserted, so, then, when im calling it in mypage:

```html
<td align="right">
<div id="body">
<textarea id="txt" rows="20" cols="48">
</textarea>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" onClick="doQuery('SELECT',txtarea.value)" value="Execute SQL">
</td>
```

I'm getting alert(2) instead of alert(1), why?

`txtarea.value` of course, is `textarea` object, so whats wrong?

Comment: For starters you might want to indent your code so it is readable.  Also why is the errorHandler function declared inside the doQuery function?

Comment: there is no meaning. I've tried to put it inside of each condition but havent any success. it works fine but only when i using only one datahandler within doQuery at a time, if i'll declare more datahandlers it will always execute last of them (as if i dont put them into conditons ), just dont know how it works

Comment: i also added at the begining of doQuery "alert((queryType == "SELECT"))" to check what is returned, it works fine, but after that it always output alert(2) , here it seems to need a specific approach to work with js database api, i cant explain it else

Answer (score 0):

I would take all the function definitions out of the first else block (get rid of that else). Change the name of the second dataHandler function to dataHandler2 and see what you get.